# Using pytest-xdist causes AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, attributeerror, xdist

I am trying to use pytest-xdist to run my tests faster by running on multiple CPUs. However, when I switch to using multiple CPUs the tests don't run because there is an error when collecting the tests.

More specifically, the error is

```
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'
```

This is because the scripts being tested import a logging module I wrote. The logging module uses

```
__main__.__file__
```

to determine the name of the main application for purposes of adding it to the log output filename.

I can't seem to figure out what pytest is doing differently in multiple CPU mode than in single CPU mode.

So when I execute my tests as

```
python3 -m pytest
```

everything runs just fine, but once I switch to

```
python3 -m pytest -n 4
```

I get these errors:

```
____________________ ERROR collecting ***.py
***/logging/log_setup.py:21: in <module>
    app_name = os.path.basename(__main__.__file__)[:-3]
E   AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'
```

The same problem occurs when I try to execute using the Python subprocess method:

```
python3 -m pytest -d --tx 3*popen//python=python3
```

**EDIT:**
I am side stepping the issue for now with the following code in my logging module:

```
if hasattr(__main__, '__file__'):
    app_name = os.path.basename(__main__.__file__)[:-3]
else:
    app_name = 'unknown_app_name'
```

Now pytest with multiple CPUs works fine for me.

Comment: what is the output of `dir(__main__)` in both scenarios?

Comment: With multiple CPUs it is: 
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'execmodel', 'get_execmodel', 'init_popen_io', 'serve', 'sys']

Comment: With one CPU it is: ['Class', 'Collector', 'File', 'Function', 'Instance', 'Item', 'Module', 'Package', 'PytestAssertRewriteWarning', 'PytestCacheWarning', 'PytestCollectionWarning', 'PytestConfigWarning', 'PytestDeprecationWarning', 'PytestExperimentalApiWarning', 'PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning', 'PytestUnknownMarkWarning', 'PytestWarning',

Comment: 'RemovedInPytest4Warning', 'Session', 'UsageError', '__all__', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__pytestPDB', '__spec__', '__version__', '_fillfuncargs', 'approx', 'cmdline', 'deprecated_call', 'exit', 'fail', 'fixture', 'freeze_includes', 'hookimpl', 'hookspec', 'importorskip', 'main', 'mark', 'param', 'pytest', 'raises', 'register_assert_rewrite', 'set_trace', 'skip', 'warns', 'xfail', 'yield_fixture']

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @hoefling if this isn't enough context for you then I highly doubt you will be able to resolve the issue

Comment: I'd say this is just arrogance. Without the code, there's little chance someone will be able to guess what the underlying error is. Therefore proposing to close this.

Comment: why can't you use `__main__.__name__` as a value for `app_name`?